# boolean confirm result

Tags: circuit-analysis, boolean-algebra

I have solve an exercise and I would like to know if I find the result right. Is there a way so I can check that my solution is right? I think this method is called De Morgan.

I had this [image]

and I find the result (A' + (AB)' + C').
The ' it means NOT.
Can  someone tell me if my solution is right? and what would be a good way to test that I find the right result?
thanks in advance guys!

Comment: You could use any programming language and compare the two expressions. If their resulting value is equal for all possible values of A, B and C they are equivalent. That should be easy to do with some for loops.

Comment: How did you get to that solutions? Your solution is longer than the original problem, so I'm not sure *why* you made the transformations to get there?

Comment: @jDAQ ... or a piece of paper, a pencil and literally a table with 8 rows

Comment: @MarcusMüller sure, use the _computer_ of your choice

Comment: "You could use any programming language and compare the two expressions".I  am not sure if I got it right .You mean I should use something like C,or Java language?

Comment: (A' + (AB)' + C')= A’ + C’ + ( A’ + B’) = A’+B’+C’=(ABC)’

Comment: How did you get to that solutions? Your solution is longer than the original problem, so I'm not sure why you made the transformations to get there?=you mean you want my truth table ?I did the truth table and then I find it that equation . I want not to correct me someone in every exercise  I want me to correct myself somehow too.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 yes if you simplifie it that it is

Comment: Yes simplify is good

Comment: but  does that my solution is right for De Morgan?sorry my bad english

Comment: Yes 
not (A or B) = not A and not B.   
not (A and B) = not A or not B

Comment: thanks a lot man